# Converting for loop to while loop in Python

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, while-loop, sum

While preparing for my exam, I got stuck at converting 'for' to 'while' statement.

```
a= int(input('type to calculate the sum of multiples'))

total =0
for i in range(1,101,1):
    if i %a==0:
        total= total+i
    else:
        continue
print('the sum of multiple numbers from 1 to ', a, 'is', total)


a= int(input('type to calculate the sum of multiples'))

ntotal =0
i=1
while i<101: 
    if i %a==0:
        ntotal = ntotal + i
    else:
        continue
print('the sum of multiple numbers from 1 to ', a, 'is', total)
```

When run in IDLE, the first part works well, however the second part does not show the result.

What should I edit to make the second part function properly?

Comment: Fix the indentation of your `if` statements.

Comment: add `i += 1` to your while loop, otherwise i will stay equal to 1 forever.

Comment: Why do you need `else: continue`? `continue` is only needed when you want to restart the loop without executing the rest of the body, but there is no rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All loops work on the repeated increment of a number or iteration through a list (collection of elements).

In your while loop, the value of `i` remains the same if `i%a` is equal to `0` or not. Either way, `i` remains unchanged, even though `ntotal` increases. So, the condition of the loop always remains `1 < 101`, which is `True`

To rectify this, you should add step-value increment to `i` as follows:

```
while i<101: 
    if i %a==0:
        ntotal = ntotal + i
    else:
        pass
    i = i + 1
```

This ensures that `i` will be incremented irrespective of whether the `if` condition is executed, or the `else` condition.

If you are uncomfortable with the usage of `pass`, you can do this:

```
while i<101: 
    if i %a==0:
        ntotal = ntotal + i
        i += 1
    else:
        i += 1
        continue
```

You don't even have to use `continue`, because after the else condition, the control of the loop will go back to the `while` loop's condition (it will repeat). I've just left it there if you want to add some other code after the `if-else`, but within the loop.

Also, as pointed out in the comments, there is no need to use the `else` clause, because nothing is being done in it. So, your code can look like:

```
while i<101: 
    if i %a==0:
        ntotal = ntotal + i

    i = i + 1
```

Comment: It also remains the same if `i%a` is equal to 0. That test has nothing to do with it.

Comment: There's no use in having an `else:` clause if all it contains is `pass` - and repeating `i += 1` in both the `if` and `else` doesn't make it better...

Comment: @ThierryLathuille I'm aware of that, but I thought that maintaining the OP's use of if-else would help him understand better (or faster)

Comment: Well, I would also have advised to remove the `else` clauses in the original code, as they serve no purpose and just make it harder to read.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille Taken into consideration - editing now!